# Merging two datasets on Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two datasets:
The first has the data for the beginning of the registration process and the second one for its end. I have users’ ids and the date.

The example of the first one (the beginning of the registration process):

```
User ID Time
1111111 2016-01-26 13:02:22
1111111 2016-01-26 14:05:51
1111111 2016-01-26 14:58:08
1111111 2016-01-27 11:17:09
1111111 2016-01-27 12:05:17
1111111 2016-01-27 13:15:33
1111111 2016-01-27 18:10:12
1111111 2016-01-27 20:23:38
222222 2016-01-29 09:01:00
222222 2016-01-29 09:04:15
222222 2016-01-29 11:27:35
222222 2016-01-30 09:02:36
222222 2016-06-29 08:50:02
333333 2016-01-26 09:58:27
```

And the second one (the end of the registration process):

```
User ID Time
1111111 2016-01-26 13:37:54
1111111 2016-01-26 14:40:34
1111111 2016-01-26 15:21:53
1111111 2016-01-27 11:42:58
1111111 2016-01-27 12:43:52
1111111 2016-01-27 13:39:56
1111111 2016-01-27 18:41:01
1111111 2016-01-27 20:51:56
222222 2016-01-29 09:17:26
222222 2016-01-29 11:37:10
222222 2016-01-30 09:16:33
333333 2016-01-29 09:14:39
```

I need to calculate the time it takes for the user to complete the registration process. The problem is that the first dataset has much more rows than the second one as the user may start the process and then just abandon it, so I cannot just merge on index. e.g.:
Two beginnings:

```
222222 2016-01-29 09:01:00
222222 2016-01-29 09:04:15
```

And just one end:

```
222222 2016-01-29 09:17:26
```

Is there a nice way to use merge/merge_asof function  to do it?

Comment: So ...  which one in your example should be ignored?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the dataframes and what they mean? For example column names, what you are trying to achieve etc? See here for creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's the list of the events that I got from the reporting API. The first dataset shows the beginning of the registration process and the second one - of the end. I need to calculate the average time difference. I hope I've clarified my question.

Comment: You  can use merge function in pandas and use left join to get matching rows from right and all rows from left.Below is code sample .                             df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='Column1', right_on='ColumnA')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUUC, you can use `merge_asof`. This will allow you to join the two DataFrames on exact matches for the `'User ID'` and Date, and then you can select the closest time in the End DataFrame (`df_end`) that is after the time in the Start DataFrame (`df_beg`)

```
import pandas as pd

# Need to convert to datetime and sort the keys we will merge_asof on.
df_beg['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_beg.Time)
df_end['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_end.Time)
df_beg = df_beg.sort_values('Time').rename(columns={'Time': 'Time_start'})
df_end = df_end.sort_values('Time').rename(columns={'Time': 'Time_end'})

merged = pd.merge_asof(df_beg, df_end,
              left_by=['User ID', df_beg.Time_start.dt.date], 
              right_by=['User ID', df_end.Time_end.dt.date],
              left_on='Time_start', right_on='Time_end',
              direction='forward').drop(columns='key_1)
```

`merged` is now:

```
    User ID          Time_start            Time_end
0    333333 2016-01-26 09:58:27                 NaT
1   1111111 2016-01-26 13:02:22 2016-01-26 13:37:54
2   1111111 2016-01-26 14:05:51 2016-01-26 14:40:34
3   1111111 2016-01-26 14:58:08 2016-01-26 15:21:53
4   1111111 2016-01-27 11:17:09 2016-01-27 11:42:58
5   1111111 2016-01-27 12:05:17 2016-01-27 12:43:52
6   1111111 2016-01-27 13:15:33 2016-01-27 13:39:56
7   1111111 2016-01-27 18:10:12 2016-01-27 18:41:01
8   1111111 2016-01-27 20:23:38 2016-01-27 20:51:56
9    222222 2016-01-29 09:01:00 2016-01-29 09:17:26
10   222222 2016-01-29 09:04:15 2016-01-29 09:17:26
11   222222 2016-01-29 11:27:35 2016-01-29 11:37:10
12   222222 2016-01-30 09:02:36 2016-01-30 09:16:33
13   222222 2016-06-29 08:50:02                 NaT
```

---

If you need to then calculate the average time as you indicate in the comments you need to jump through a few hoops due to the `timedelta64` datatype.

```
import numpy as np

mask = merged.Time_end.notnull()
# Calculate the time difference and convert to a numeric type
merged.loc[mask, 'Time_diff'] = (merged.loc[mask, 'Time_end'] 
                                 - merged.loc[mask, 'Time_start']).astype(np.int64)

# Calculate the average time difference, convert back to timedelta.
pd.to_timedelta(merged.groupby('User ID').Time_diff.mean())
#User ID
#222222    00:13:17.250000
#333333                NaT
#1111111   00:30:14.250000
#Name: Time_diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```